# Payment Processors - re-arrange in rows

Tags: civievent, contributions, payment

Event registration is listing payment processors in coloumns - which makes the radio buttons unreadable on small screens, dont know what is the best way to change the orienetation. I've included a screenshot how we would like it to be.
[image]

Comment: Can you submit a pull request for the fix?

Comment: @PradeepNayak Thank you for encouraging, now that I started looking at how can i make a start on contributing, followed https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/tools/buildkit/ to create vagrant environment. 

I completed installation of vagrant box and is able to go to virtualbox running ubuntu/64.

when i try visting http://d7-master.test/ from browser all i see is php code 

<?php
/**
 * If a custom ..
</html>


I'had spent 4 days trying to debug, but looks like i need guidance to progress further

Any guidance and pointers will be very helpful